# Cannot generate a lot of unique strings

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, unique-constraint

I've got a problem while trying to update a column with a unique string in PostgreSQL. I have a table with about 30kk records in it. What I want is to set a unique `sha1` value to a specific column (let's call it `fieldName`), but only for those rows where this column is `NULL` - there are about 20kk records of that kind in the table. There is a `UNIQUE` constraint of the `fieldName` column.

So, I wrote a simple query:

```
UPDATE tableName 
  SET fieldName = 
      ENCODE(
          DIGEST(CONCAT('salt_string, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW()), random()), 'sha1'), 
      'hex')
WHERE fieldName IS NULL
```

But I always get an error `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "..."` after some time of executing this query.

So I would like to ask whether there is something wrong with the way I genereate a unique string. Maybe it's not "random" enough? Or did I miss anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your salt string is the same for every execution and if the timestamp you are using is the same as well, i.e. if the time between executions is less than the precision of the time variable (seconds, milliseconds or nanoseconds probably), then you get the same pseudo random value result.

To enrich your seed for the random value generation, use a sequence:

```
CREATE TEMP SEQUENCE my_own_sequence;
UPDATE tableName 
  SET fieldName = 
      ENCODE(
          DIGEST(CONCAT('salt_string, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW(), nextval('my_own_sequence')), random()), 'sha1'), 
      'hex')
WHERE fieldName IS NULL;
```

You can read more about creating sequences here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html

Comment: Thanks for helping! I suspected that the problem was in `sameness` of the string, but I also hoped that `random()` function would be enough to guaranty it's uniqueness.